# add html tags in excel sheet for product descriptions

Tags: product, csv, html

we are planning to upload products using "import products" using csv.

we have lot of descriptions , we have to display description in table format.

is there any way to add html tags in excel sheet.

please help me to find some solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes surely you can add that. Create your data in excel sheet, save it as CSV. 
Excel will automatically add double quotes for that column with string as value, to be sure open csv in notepad and check you data..

Comment: i did't got, i am uploading new products.

suppose if we export the products, we will get the ctaegory ids, 

if we are uploading new products? how we have to assign the new products to categories?

Comment: assign categories id in the column for the new rows/products...in short create a new product row similar to exported csv just that update the data accordingly.

Comment: what was point of unaccepting the answer, also your original question and the comment you posted recently is no where related ? My answer to to above original question was about putting html tables in csv file.....

Comment: did you got your answer about categories id ?